# How to push variable JavaScript into aodata datatable

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, datatable

I have variable named `search_gen`. This Variable is generated from ajax(code show below).

```
var search_gen;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: link+module_name+'search_generator/'+module_active,
    dataType: "text",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        search_gen = data; //or something similar
    }
});
```

for example this variable will contain a json data(show bellow)

```
{"name":"room_type_name","value":$("#room_type_name").val()},{"name":"room_type_code","value":$("#room_type_code"
).val()}
```

if i place json above without using variable it work example code bellow

```
table=$('#table').dataTable({
  "sScrollY": "400px",
   "bFilter": false,
  "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sServerMethod": "GET",
    "sAjaxSource": link+module_name+'populate_list/'+module_active,
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "columnDefs": [ {
           "targets": 0,
           "orderable": false
           },
           {
           "targets": -1,
           "orderable": false
           } ],
  "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
    aoData.push({"name":"room_type_name","value":$("#room_type_name").val()},
                 {"name":"room_type_code","value":$("#room_type_code").val()})
                }
})
```

and when I'm using variable and put into bracket `aodata(seach_gen)` (code Below)

```
  table=$('#table').dataTable({
      "sScrollY": "400px",
       "bFilter": false,
      "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sServerMethod": "GET",
        "sAjaxSource": link+module_name+'populate_list/'+module_active,
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "columnDefs": [ {
               "targets": 0,
               "orderable": false
               },
               {
               "targets": -1,
               "orderable": false
               } ],
      "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        aoData.push(search_gen)
}
    });
```

It shows an error like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENS7G.png)

My question is
how do I pass my variable `search_gen` into `aodata.push()`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not waiting for the first AJAX call to complete before calling `.dataTable`. Try following code:

```
var search_gen;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: link+module_name+'search_generator/'+module_active,
    dataType: "text",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        search_gen = data; //or something similar
    }
}).done(function( data ) {
  table=$('#table').dataTable({
      "sScrollY": "400px",
       "bFilter": false,
      "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sServerMethod": "GET",
        "sAjaxSource": link+module_name+'populate_list/'+module_active,
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "columnDefs": [ {
               "targets": 0,
               "orderable": false
               },
               {
               "targets": -1,
               "orderable": false
               } ],
      "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        //aoData.push(search_gen)
        Array.prototype.push.apply(aoData,search_gen); // <<<<<<<<<<<< use this
      }
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you can call `.dataTable` inside `success` callback of first `$.ajax` and use `data` parameter in place of `search_gen`, like `aoData.push(data)`.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment I think `search_gen` is an array, in which case you will need to use `Array.prototype.push.apply(aoData,search_gen);` instead of `aoData,.push(search_gen);`. Check the code above.

Comment: i already try what u suggest to but it still not work. and still have a same error message.